# Slider not showing on my JScrollPane, used code I got from stack overflow

Tags: java

I looked at the solution for this on stack overflow, and its not working for me. My code:

```
public cTextWin( String name, int id, String body) throws Exception 
{
    super(name,id);

    JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout() );

    textArea = new JTextArea(body);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    containerPanel.add(scrollPane);
    containerPanel.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(containerPanel);
}
```

Comment: share the answer that you got the code from please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, if you copy and paste a chunk of GUI code it's not going to run properly. You should do some research about the minimum requirements for getting a GUI setup. It's not clear from your code if you're running from a swing thread, initialized variables, adding and showing the JFrame... etc.

**It's not going to be clear that you have a JScrollPane unless you set the scroll policy or insert enough text to force scrolling.** You'll have to play with the layout manager and sizes of your components.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createGUI() {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        addComp(jf.getContentPane());

        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.pack();
    }

    public static void addComp(Container pane) {
        JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout() );

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("stuff");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea); 
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        containerPanel.add(scrollPane);
        containerPanel.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pane.add(containerPanel);
    }
}
```